# multcompare and anova1 yield completely different p-values

Tags: matlab

I am trying to see if there are significant differences between 7 groups of data I measured. I first did this by doing a separate anova1 test for each group with all other groups, resulting in 21 different p-values. The level of significance will be corected with a bonferroni correction, so I assumed that this would just mean that the level of significance becomes 0.05/21.

However when I use the multcompare function in combination with anova1, to compare all groups, with a bonferroni correction, I get completely different p-values. I get that the bonferroni correction will change the p-values, but I don't get why for example the anova1 p-value of 0.0016 becomes 1.000, while the value of 0.0070 becomes 00019. Is there someone that can tell me what is happening, because both methods are just comparing the means of each group with the other groups?

The left column shows the p-values of the individual anova1 tests and the right column that of the multcompare.

```
0.0496    1.0000
0.0016    1.0000
0.0658    1.0000
0.2019    1.0000
0.7105    1.0000
0.0070    0.0019
0.3264    1.0000
0.8264    1.0000
0.4494    1.0000
0.1246    1.0000
0.0613    0.1402
0.5911    1.0000
0.0370    1.0000
0.0106    1.0000
0.1207    0.6513
0.4404    1.0000
0.1834    1.0000
0.0942    0.2323
0.1876    1.0000
0.0738    0.1048
0.0966    0.0607
```